# How to enable nullptr from C++0x in the Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, nullptr

I wonder how can I enable the nullptr in the just released Visual Studio 2010. (C++ project, not managed).

This is one of the new features but it is not available by default and looking inside the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ex65770(VS.100).aspx it seams that it is enabled by `/clr` but this is managed!

Is this a feature added only for .NET?

Comment: It should work fine. It states that you should use `__nullptr` when you want to use the native `nullptr` in managed code, but as you're not compiling with `/clr`, you should be fine.

Comment: What do you mean it's "not available by default"? If I create a plain C++ project I can use nullptr just fine. C++/CLI has a slightly different nullptr, but that's only enabled with /clr

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 installed on 3 computers. The same project compiles fine on 2 of them, on the 3rd, nullptr gives compile errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply created a new C++ Win32 console project in VS2010RC and nullptr keyword was just available to use as they have shown in the examples.